# How do i integrate GOOGLE PAY IN payment method without using any extension in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to integrate Google pay payment method in my website without using any existing extension. Please help me how for this.

Comment: I think you have create custom extension for google pay in magento1.9 . You can use this sdk https://github.com/google-pay/passes-rest-samples/tree/master/php

Comment: no i want a headless structure.

Comment: then you have to create custom extension for google pay in magento1.9

Comment: did you find any extension for Magento 1?